# BufferedRead reading binary file differently on Linux vs Windows

Tags: java, linux

I'm writing a Java program to post-process a binary file with 1 or more Test packets with various amounts of
data. I parse through the binary file with a BufferedReader object. Since my program's purpose is to update the packet
sizes, I parse through the packets until I reach the next packet indicated by the packet header "Test".

My program works fine on my Windows 7 PC, but it doesn't work on my Linux machine for some reason. It simply is not
correctly finding and reading the packet data the same way that my PC is, but I'm not sure why.

I have tried both:

```
        private final int PACKET_DATA_SIZE          = 4;
        char[] packetData = new char[PACKET_DATA_SIZE];

        while( !tempString.equals("Test") ) {
            read(br, packetData, PACKET_DATA_SIZE);
            tempString = new String(packetData);

            if ( currentLocation >= fileSize ) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

and

```
        while( currentLocation < fileSize ) {
            read(br, packetData, PACKET_DATA_SIZE);

            if (packetData[0] == 'T' && packetData[1] == 'e' && packetData[2] == 's' && packetData[3] == 't') {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Both use my read function:

```
public void read(BufferedReader br, char[] cbuf, int length) {
    try {
        br.read(cbuf, 0, length);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentLocation += length;
}
```

Both work fine on Win7, but again, not on my Linux machine. How/why is Linux interpreting the characters
in the raw binary file differently than Windows? Both binary files are written the exact same way byte for byte. Thank you

Comment: If you do it on Win7 and print the binary of the result file out, how is that different than the same printout of the binary result file created on Linux?

Comment: what is writing the file in the first place?  Is it java code?

Comment: @TritonMan A c++ program is writing the binary file.

Comment: that could possibly be your problem, at least if the CPUs are different architectures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc for `BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) says:

> Reads **text** from a **character-input stream**

Text! Not binary!

Use, for instance, a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) instead.

Or go the full way to java.nio and use a [`FileChannel` and map your file in memory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) (and have a look at what [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) has to offer -- for instance you have a `.asCharBuffer()` to read `char`s and you can alter endianness as well)

Comment: I didn't catch that, but yeah this is probably the problem.  Also, why use Buffered when you are reading byte by byte?

Comment: @TritonMan good question... Which is why I use nio in any case: I can always instantiate a `*Stream` from any `ByteBuffer` ;)

Comment: @TritonMan buffering in any context (I/O, graphics, etc.) is intended to improve performance.  Suppose you have a buffer of 1024 bytes.  One sequential read is needed.  Without a buffer, 1024 reads are needed (though the OS may perform some optimization on its own).  Try timing how long it takes to read a 500 MB file with and without wrapping the FileInputStream in a BufferedInputStream; the buffered one will always be faster.

Comment: @rob with an mmap()ed file this doesn't matter, since the OS does the buffering for you... FileChannel rocks!

Comment: @fge I was just responding to "why used Buffered when you are reading byte by byte?"  But yes, I did not clarify that you wouldn't necessarily gain the performance benefit from wrapping a memory-mapped file's InputStream in a BufferedInputStream.

Comment: @fge Thank you for catching my mistake. Using BufferedInputStream worked!

Comment: @kaghaffa no problem ;) When in doubt, read the javadoc; when not in doubt, read it again ;)

Answer (score 2):

> BufferedReader reading binary

Stop right there. Three words into the question and this is is already wrong. Readers are for text files. Don't use them on anything you don't know to be text.